# How to fit probability density function in R?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

```
nscore <- function(x) {
nscore <- qqnorm(x, plot.it = FALSE)$x}
x=1:15
a=nscore(x)
> a
 [1] -1.8339146 -1.2815516 -0.9674216 -0.7279133 -0.5244005 -0.3406948 -0.1678940  0.0000000
 [9]  0.1678940  0.3406948  0.5244005  0.7279133  0.9674216  1.2815516  1.8339146
```

Now I want to fit a pdf to normal score (a) with mean of 0.15 and sd of 0.8:

```
> dnorm(a,mean=0.15,sd=0.8)
 [1] 0.02303523 0.10057599 0.18800478 0.27309675 0.34954603 0.41316615 0.46082107 0.48998862
 [9] 0.49855312 0.48470988 0.44695057 0.38415091 0.29587771 0.18339473 0.05441677
```

Is this a correct way to get a pdf from a normal score?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a "predictive" pdf?  How does it differ from a probability density function?

Comment: Here, I want to fit a probability density function .

Comment: I can't make any sense of your code and do not understand at all what you are trying to achieve with it... Could you describe *in words* what you are trying to achieve? What do you mean by "fitting pdf"? Usually by "fitting" distribution to data we mean finding such parameters from the data that make the distribution "best fitted" to the data (e.g. your data has empirical sd = 4.5, so if you fit normal distribution you use sigma = 4.5). In you case you seem to know the parameters in advance so there is nothing to fit...

Comment: I have a non normal dataset called x. I want to transform it to normal space which has been done here using nscore function.I am assuming  sd at first to get the pdf . My goal here is to fit the best pdf assuming different sd. So, Can I fit the pdf with the nscore values here? Does it make sense to fit pdf with the nscore values?

Comment: By "fit the pdf" do you mean "estimate the parameters of the pdf"?

Comment: I am trying to improve the pdf when the sd in not known.